# How to automatically calculate and display next due date based on user selected options and input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I created a form using antd proform with 4 fields. The first field is an input number named interval, the second is a select field with 2 options: "day(s)" and "month(s)", the third and fourth are datepicker fields. For example, if the user enters 30 as an interval, selects "days", and selects 2023-08-10 as the last due date,  the next due date should be calculated automatically and displayed (2023-09-09) in the fourth field. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
<ProForm.Group>
    <ProFormDigit 
        onChange={(value) => setIntervalDays(value)} 
        name="interval" 
        label="Interval" />
    <ProFormSelect
        onChange={(value) => setKindOfDate(value)}
        name="kindOfDate"
        label=""
        options={[
            {
              value: "1",
              label: "Day(s)",
            },
            {
              value: "2",
              label: "Month(s)",
            },
        ]}
    />
</ProForm.Group>
<ProForm.Group>
    <ProFormDatePicker 
        onChange={(value) => setLastDueDate(value)} 
        name="lastDueDate" 
        label="Last Due Date" 
    />
    <ProFormDatePicker 
        onChange={(value) => setNextDueDate(value)} 
        name="nextDueDate" 
        label="Next Due Date" 
    />
</ProForm.Group>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the Date object of javascript isn't the best (in my opinion), you have better libraries that can do the work in such a great way.

Let's say the form part is done (get user input values).

You can do it with Date object like this :

```js
// Convert the lastDueDate to Date object
const date = new Date(lastDueDate)

// create your nextDueDate depending on which interval and unit you chose
if (unit === 'days') {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + intervalValue)
} else if (unit === 'months') {
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + intervalValue)
}

const year = date.getFullYear()
const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0')
const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')

console.log(`Next due date: ${year}-${month}-${day}`)
```

Or, you can simply add "moment" library to your project and use this function :

```js
// import moment
import moment from 'moment'

const calculateDueDate = (interval, unit, dueDate) => {
   const nextDueDate = moment(dueDate).add(interval, unit);
   return nextDueDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}
```

Hope it helps, i can help you more if you need to fetch values and call the function correctly.

Comment: Note:  `moment.js` is pretty dead these days, there is a more modern https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/   but even then, if all the OP want to do is add 30 days, adding a 23k lib is a bit overkill.

Comment: Note: "pretty dead" doesn't mean you can't use it. However, i'll edit my message and add a "javascript native" way to achieve it.

Comment: Correct, you can still use it.